# Ajax.BeginForm ends error (500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem.

I use bootstrap modalpopup for delete element.
When I click delete, modal with comfirm delete show. If I click submit button delete method is finish success but in Developer tools (chrome) show error (500 (Internal Server Error)) and modalpopup with shadow layer no hiden. I'm not sure how well I created my methods. When I change ActionResult in controller to void and my method Delete() no return value the modal behave properly but the table with my element no refresh. I tired use UpdateTargetId in AjaxOptions but shadow from modalpopup no hiden and updateTergetid render whole page. I don't know what should return my controller method Delete()

controller:

```
        [HttpPost]    
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            _facade.Delete(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", _controllerName);
        }
```

view:

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete", ViewData["controllerName"].ToString(), new
                {
                    id = @Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["routeValues"])
                },
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "$('#delete-element-id').modal('hide');"
}))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()                         
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />


                }
```

Comment: Your POST method makes no sense - it has `return RedirectToAction()` but your using `Ajax.BeginForm()` which will NEVER redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page.)

Comment: If I change Delete method to return void and Delete RedirectToAction(), the element on page no refresh. I tired use UpdateTargetId but the shadow on back my model no hidde. What type should be my Delete method and whether it should use UpdateTargetId? What other solution?